# Updating android URI scheme with android play store update

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

I have altered our androidManifest.xml to the new name of our uri scheme (to match branches UI), and deeplinks now work great if the app is installed from the play store. But when our app is already installed and just updates it isn't having the correct behavior.

Is there a way to make android playstore updates reinstall the app, or force the app to update the xml on an update?

From what I read it should already be doing that but I'm getting weird behavior. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When we update the app via the play store the entire APK or bundle is downloaded and installed. Play store does not update the app in bits and pieces. 
You can either force the users for an app update via your app code in order to continue usage. Alternatively, you can share a pop-up message on all outdated versions to update the app in order to access all features.
These will be viable options to proceed on as Play Store does not have any functionality to make it mandatory for the app to be updated.
Also, requesting you to perform a sanity check on your end to see what is the percentage of the error you are facing. On an update, the app should be on the new production build and everything should be working as expected to.

I hope the above helps here.

Comment: Awesome okay thank you. I am going to do some more testing to see if/what is actually changing. If the whole APK is being replaced then that should fix the problem. Weirdly I remember seeing in some docs that a reinstall was necessary to update something that I changed but can't find it anywhere now!